# Using attachment's name in pipe command from Mutt

Tags: mutt

Is there any special variable for retrieving an attachment's name when piping it from Mutt?

I want to do something like this:

```
Pipe to: cat > /some/folder/$attachment_name
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566124/85046 There's no way of getting attachment filename in a variable now. But see the workaround using mailcap.