# Recovering mutt attachment filenames

Tags: mutt, ranger

I have a small `mutt` macro to save attachments using my file manager (`ranger`, as it happens). It looks like this:

```
macro attach S "<pipe-message>muttsaveattach"<enter>
```

where `mutttsaveattach` is the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
urxvt -e ranger --choosefile=/tmp/muttattach
cat > $"`cat /tmp/muttattach`"
```

This is clunky, but works. What it does is dump the attachment into `/tmp/muttattach`, and then save the contents of that file into a file you create using `ranger`.

The only thing I miss is being somehow able to recover the original name of the attachment and using it in my script. Is there any variable that `mutt` provides, for use in macros, that holds this value? If there isn't, is there any other way to recover and use this name?

Comment: It seems the filename is only available when saving the attachment. Is it OK if you first save the attachment to a known folder, and then open ranger on that folder pointing at the newest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible right now with this approach. Mutt and Neomutt doesn't have any variable available to user that can give you the filename. But I have an idea how to achieve it using mailcap.

**Let's say you have a macro which does following:**

- saves current `mailcap_path` to a variable,
- sets a new `mailcap_path` (see mailcap file example below),
- forces to view attachment using mailcap,
- restore `mailcap_path` to previous path.

```
macro attach S\
<enter-command>set my_mailcap_path=$mailcap_path<enter>\
<enter-command>set mailcap_path=~/.mailcap2<enter>\
<view-mailcap>\
<enter-command>set mailcap_path=$my_mailcap_path<enter>\
```

You would need to create a mailcap entry for every possible mailcap type (not including subtypes, you can use could be wildcards.

**Sample ~/.mailcap2**

```
application/*; /your/script %s
audio/*;       /your/script %s
font/*;        /your/script %s
image/*;       /your/script %s
message/*;     /your/script %s
model/*;       /your/script %s
text/*;        /your/script %s
video/*;       /your/script %s
```

You would need to change your script a little. Because the attachment won't be piped to it anymore. It will get the file name as an argument. Or maybe try to change mailcap2 file directly to contain `filetype/*; urxvt -e ranger --choosefile=%s`

```
#!/bin/sh
urxvt -e ranger --choosefile=$1
```

Also I'm not 100% sure, but It's probably necessary to rip off the first command of a macro `<enter-command>set my_mailcap_path=$mailcap_path<enter>\` out and have the variable assigned before. I think I encountered this before. Setting and unsetting a variable within a single macro doesn't play well.

disclaimer: I didn't test it, but I'm pretty positive this should work.

Comment: This is even clunkier than what I am currently doing :) But I believe you that this is the best we can currently do. Thanks!